# Can Google Analytics track our partner's subpages?

Tags: google, google-analytics

Our site has some partners, and every partner has their own unique sub-page (like: `www.example.com/john`, `www.example.com/tony` etc.), with every partner having content in the relevant sub-folder (`www.example.com/partnername/contact`, `www.example.com/partnername/bio` ...)

I want to track partner pages so I can produce report on the partners' "success".

It this possible with Google Analytics?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you can place tracking code on the page you want to track.

Page by page, no matter where is the page located.

Comment: Right answer, but if you can, provide some links and examples.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I get your question correctly. I'm not sure if it qualifies for competitor analysis.

Anyway, **if the page is on same domain and all the pages carry the analytics script then it is possible to track all the pages under same domain, multiple subdomains or folders**.

All you need to do is put the analytics code in all the pages. If the code is not placed in all the pages then there is no way to track the individual folders or subdomains. In such cases, analytics or any similar external web stat tool fails.

If you have a server credentials then you can read the server logs - Awstats, webalizer etc for this information. That is the only last option for tracking.